# how to change Qt qListView Icon selection highlight

Tags: qt, icons, highlighting, selected, qlistview

When using qlistview in icon mode I need to completely remove the hilighting when a icon is selected.
Using the code below the text under the icon is no longer highlighted but I still get blue color over the icon when selected

```
 QString stylesheet = "";
   stylesheet += "QListView::item:alternate {background-image: transparent; background-color: transparent;}";
   stylesheet += "QListView::item:selected {background-image: transparent; background-color: transparent;padding: 0px;color: black;}";
   stylesheet += "QListView::item:selected:active{background-image: transparent;background-color: transparent; color: black;}";
   stylesheet += "QListView::item:selected:!active{background-image: transparent;background-color: transparent;color: black;}";
   setStyleSheet(stylesheet);
```

does anyone know how to change the selected color over the icon without having to subclass QStandardItem?

Comment: What version of Qt are you using?  I am running 4.7.1 and I never see the icon highlighted at all, even without your style sheet.

Answer (score 13):

For a QListView with QStandardItem's it's possible to do what you want. Simply create an icon an add the same pixmap for both normal and selected states. Then setIcon in the item

```
QIcon icon;

icon.addPixmap(yourPixmap,QIcon::Normal);
icon.addPixmap(yourPixmap,QIcon::Selected);

qstandardItem.setIcon(icon);
```

Comment: I've finally found my answer! thx so much! But to remove FocusRect from every other place, this answer worked for me https://forum.qt.io/topic/87212/how-to-remove-blue-focus-rectangle/2

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer. could not remove the section color overlay in QListview without using delegate but after switching to use QListWidget I could disable the selection overlay by setting a selected icon image